# Creating HibernateTemplate by org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: spring, hibernate, datasource

I work with Spring 3.1 + Hibernate 4.

I've created the following `sessionFactory`:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.my.company"/>
</bean>
```

As you see, the above `sessionFactory` is for Hibernate 4.

**I am trying to crate a `HibernateTemplate`** (`org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate`) **through Java code, by that `sessionFactory`**, but I am not sure how to do this.

I've tried the following code:

```
@Resource(name="sessionFactory")
public void setSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory) {
    this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory.getObject());
}
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'sessionFactory' must be of type [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean], but was actually of type [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl]
```

Could you show how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As from [this post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?117227-Missing-Hibernate-Classes-Interfaces-in-spring-orm-3.1.0.RC1#post_386881):

> HibernateTemplate isn't recommended for use anymore (about since the
>   release of hibernate 3.0.1) there is no more added value so that isn't
>   going to be in there anymore for hibernate 4. Simply use the plain
>   SessionFactory and use the getCurrentSession method to obtain the
>   current transactional session (don't use openSession!!!!) and you are
>   good to go...

From the javadoc of package **org.springframework.orm.hibernate4**:

> Contains an implementation of Spring's transaction SPI for local
>   Hibernate transactions. This package is intentionally rather minimal,
>   with no template classes or the like, in order to follow native
>   Hibernate recommendations as closely as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You don,t need to extends any hibernate dao support class in latest version of spring. You can directly inject hibernate sessionfactory from xml/java based configuration. And it also need to be injected into transaction manger. Refer this link for better understanding:
http://hantsy.blogspot.in/2013/07/use-native-hibernate-4-api.html