# Is there any way to migrate hibernate3 to hibernate4 for java applications

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Java Spring (3.1.0.RELEASE) application and used maven (Apache Maven 3.2.5 )

I need to migrate hibernate-core 3.6.3.Final to 4.0.0.Final without changing the HibernateTemplate. What should I do?

Is there any possibility to do the migration using any command?

Comment: Change the version in the pom and see if it still works? Some extra information on the type of project would help.

Comment: What do you mean by "without changing the HibernateTemplate"?

Comment: I googled most of the link says use sessionFactory instead of HibernateTemplate. My all Dao classes are running with the HibernateTemplate but hibernate4.HibernateTemplate is deprecated from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780585/creating-hibernatetemplate-by-org-springframework-orm-hibernate4-localsessionfac

Comment: Instead of googling, you should read the documentation of hibernate3.HibernateTemplate and hibernate4.HibernateTemplate. hibernate4.HibernateTemplate is **not** deprecated. Its documentation, however, recommends **not** using it, but the documentation of hibernate3.HibernateTemplate **already recommended the same thing, for a very long time**. You didn't seem to care, so you can continue not caring and use the new HibernateTemplate, at least as a first step of the migration.